# mplfinanceのグラフを加工して、オフスクリーンレンダリング

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-lab

mplfinanceというパッケージ（内部でmatplotlibを利用していると思われる）で、グラフを作成し、
凡例を追加して、ファイルに出力したいのですが、
JupyterLab(VSCode+拡張機能)の出力結果欄にも表示されてしまい困っています。
JupyterLabの出力結果欄には、グラフを表示せず、ファイルのみに出力する方法を教えていただけないでしょうか？
もしくは、mplfinanceが作成するグラフを加工する適切な方法がありましたら、教えていただけないでしょうか。

試したコード

```
# mplfinanceのインストール
# !pip3 install --upgrade mplfinance

import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf # GoogleColabでも、追加インストールが必要

# チャート用のデータ作成
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'Open':[ 100, 110, 120, 130 ],
        'Close':[ 111, 112, 113, 114 ],
        'Low':[ 95, 91, 92, 93 ],
        'High':[ 120, 121, 122, 123 ]
    },
    index=[pd.Timestamp('2022/03/01'), pd.Timestamp('2022/03/02'), pd.Timestamp('2022/03/03'), pd.Timestamp('2022/03/04') ]
)
display(df)

# fig, axes = mpf.plot(df, returnfig=True, savefig=dict(fname='test.png',dpi=100)) # ←mplfinanceのファイル出力機能を利用すると、凡例の追加ができない。オフスクリーンレンダリングは可能
fig, axes = mpf.plot(df, returnfig=True)
axes[0].legend(labels=[ 'Candlestick' ], loc='lower left') # 凡例の追加
fig.savefig("image.png") # ←matplotlibのファイル出力機能を利用すると、凡例は追加されるが、JupyterLab(VSCode)の出力結果欄にも表示されてしまう
```

実行結果（JupyterLabには非表示のまま、ファイルに出力したい。）
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

セルの先頭にパラメータを指定しない単独の`%%capture`を挿入することで結果表示を抑制出来るようです。
[%%capture](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-capture)

> If unspecified, captured output is discarded.

こちらの記事にもあります。
[How do you suppress output in Jupyter running IPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23692950/9014308)

> This simply discards the output, but the `%%capture` magic can be used to save the output to a variable

ただし`display(df)`の方は表示を行いたい場合でも、同じセルの中では同様に抑制されてしまいますので、表示したいものがある場合はセルを分けた方が良いでしょう。
こんな風に：
セル1

```
# mplfinanceのインストール
# !pip3 install --upgrade mplfinance

import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf # GoogleColabでも、追加インストールが必要

# チャート用のデータ作成
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'Open':[ 100, 110, 120, 130 ],
        'Close':[ 111, 112, 113, 114 ],
        'Low':[ 95, 91, 92, 93 ],
        'High':[ 120, 121, 122, 123 ]
    },
    index=[pd.Timestamp('2022/03/01'), pd.Timestamp('2022/03/02'), pd.Timestamp('2022/03/03'), pd.Timestamp('2022/03/04') ]
)
display(df)
```

セル2

```
%%capture
# fig, axes = mpf.plot(df, returnfig=True, savefig=dict(fname='test.png',dpi=100)) # ←mplfinanceのファイル出力機能を利用すると、凡例の追加ができない。オフスクリーンレンダリングは可能
fig, axes = mpf.plot(df, returnfig=True)
axes[0].legend(labels=[ 'Candlestick' ], loc='lower left') # 凡例の追加
fig.savefig("image.png") # ←matplotlibのファイル出力機能を利用すると、凡例は追加されるが、JupyterLab(VSCode)の出力結果欄にも表示されてしまう
```

Comment: %%captureでうまくいきました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

セルマジック以外に, ipywidgets 使う方法も。

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
out = widgets.Output(layout={'border': '1px solid black'})

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 2), columns=["B", "C"]).cumsum()
df["A"] = pd.Series(list(range(len(df))))
display(df)
with out:
    ax = df.plot(x="A", y="B")
    df.plot(x="A", y="C", ax=ax)
    #plt.savefig('temp.svg')
    plt.show()
```

表示する場合は, `display(out)` (もしくはセルの最後の行で `out`)

関数に対してキャプチャーも可能 (printだけでなく plotもキャプチャー可能)

```py
debug_view = widgets.Output(layout={'border': '1px solid black'})

@debug_view.capture(clear_output=True)
def bad_callback(event):
    print('This is about to explode')
    return 1.0 / 0.0
```

(ちなみに `layout={'border': '1px solid black'}` は枠付けてるだけなので指定なしでも OK)

参考: [Output widgets: leveraging Jupyter’s display system](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Output%20Widget.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます。widgets.Output確認できました（Windows版で動作、Linux版で非表示にできず正しく動作しませんでしたが、私の環境設定ミスの可能性もあるので、有用な情報が得られましたら、ご報告いたします。）さらに関数単位で制御可能なところ便利ですね。